# Ng-show and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to be able to show an entire list of cities when the page first loads.

When a user clicks a checkbox for that city I want to use ng-show/ng-hide to show the results for the city selected by the user and hide the non selected cities.

I do not want to use filter as this add/removes from dom causing it to re-render.

Does anyone know best way to do this.

Comment: `ng-show="city == selectedcity"` in all checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
<label ng-init="city = {}"><input type="checkbox" ng-change="selected = true" ng-model="city['London']">London</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-change="selected = true" ng-model="city['Los Angeles']">Los Angeles</label>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul class="employees">
        <li ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-show="!selected || city[employee.city]">
        {{employee.name}}
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using `ng-repeat` to show all the cities? if yes, you could do something like this:

```
<ul class="cities">
    <li ng-repeat="city in cities" ng-show="!selectedCity">{{city}}</li>
    <li ng-show="selectedCity">{{selectedCity}}</li>
</ul>
```

once a user selects a city, your variable `selectedCity` will populate, and it'll hide the list and show the `li` with the `selectedCity` showing only.

you're have to set the variable `selectedCity` in your controller when user clicks the checkbox.

you didn't post any code, so i don't know what exactly is your implementation to show cities. i hope this example is clear.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuj4sxoz/4/) to see if this is the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7495/. On selection of London I want to hide Los Angeles and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

for example if u holds cities in $scope.cities and you repeat cities on landing page use checkbox like this in cities ng repeat

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$scope.cities[$index]['select']" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="NO" ng-click="showCitiesData(city)">
```

then in your controller

```
.controller{
 $scope.showcitydata=false;
$scope.showCities=function(city){
if(city.select=='YES;){
  $scope.showcitydata=true;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the filter into *ng-repeat* directive with object expression

```
ng-repeat="city in cities | filter:{selected:true}"
```